# NoSQL plans example

Tags: sql, database, nosql

I'm reading things about NoSQL. I know that it is not based on relations however, I can't figure out how to do some basic things. ( And I didn't found real example code about it ).

I want to store users, posts and comments.

SQL Version:

```
user's table: user_id, username
posts's table: post_id, user_id, content
comments's table: comment_id, content
```

Ok, simple.

In a NoSQL what I drafted is ( 100% functional, I'm not using any technologies like MongoDB etc for now ) :

```
users: 
{
    id: XX,
    username: "John"
},
{
        id: OO,
        username: "Mike"
}

posts:
{
    id: YY,
    content: "How are you all ?",
    user: {
        id: OO,
        username: "Mike"
    },
    comments: {
        id: ZZ,
        content: "Fine",
        user: {
            id: XX,
            username: "John"
        }
    }   
}
```

I could have stored the user's id in posts and comments in place of the entire user but I'm using NoSQL, not SQL, so I'm not doing it.

First ? Is this data-model fine for NoSQL ?

Secondly, if yes for the previous question, what if user XX ( John ) changes its username for "Tony" ? Potentially I will have to update all posts from him, and the same for each comments ?! Let's imagine he posted during it's user's life, 10 000+ comments, wtf. So I'm guessing I'm doing it wrong.

Can you clarify my misconceptions ?

Comment: You do realize that NoSQL  just means "not SQL", right? There's no standardized syntax called NoSQL, so everything depends on the database you're using. What you post is just something that looks like a JavaScript object.

Comment: NoSQL data stores (Cassandra, etc.) are usually just key value stores.  So in your case, perhaps the key would be the user ID and then yes, you would need to find a way to deal with the JSON blob to which it points.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the question is that it assumes all the NoSQL Databases work the same way, based on the problem it looks like your question might be related on how to store "Documents" (JSON) in a database in a way that you can retrieve the contents later, I will answer this from the Document Stores point of view:

As you already spotted NoSQL does not provide a relationships and therefore you will need to handle this manually. In NoSQL World de-normalization is usually the first step to ensure you can retrieve the documents in the less round-trips to the database, therefore your approach of adding the user name to the posts is the typical approach.

The problem you are stating is perfectly valid, what will happend if the user name changes? it's valid but not quite real, the usernames in a blog are usually the key for everything, so changing it it's kind of a big change, and not allowed normally.

To perform the relationships you can retrieve the documents with id later, and store the ids if required, so you normalize your database in the same way you will do in SQL world, in this case you might need to use indexes to ensure a good performance if the id is the user and not the document internal id, or use the username as id of the document itself. In djondb will be something like:

```
{ 
  "_id": "myuser",
  "name": "Cross"
}
```

and the blog will have

```
{ 
   "userid": "myuser", 
   "content": "Hello world"
}
```

Now, what if you need to update several documents?, in that case you will need djondb, a document database supporting transactions over several documents, to keep your database consistent

More about data modeling: http://djondb.com/nosql-masterdetail-sample/

More about transactions in djondb: http://djondb.com/section/transactions/

Disclaimer: I work with djondb, so I'm always biased!

Hope this helps,